# How to execute the if condition within heredoc and stored into mysql database for displayin the data in frontend

Tags: php, html, mysql

I dont know how to execute the below script

I want to display button like accept,decline in user panel for that I use mysql_fetch_row to display those values in frontend

I want to execute the condition in the below script and insert those form values into the mysql database.

If it executes these values will be displayed in users panel

but at user registration page it fails and displays error messages sql,s1,s2,rec undefined variable
please any one help how to execute this script and how to conditonal form display buttons in user panel

```
  <?php
    $str=<<<abc
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from links where column='value'");
    $sq1=mysql_fetch_row($sql);
    $s1=$rec[13];
    $s2='Done';
    if($s1==$s2)
    {
    echo "<form name=f1 method=post action=\"xxx.php\">
    <input type=hidden name=income value=$rec[value]>
    <input type=submit value=\"Accept\" id=submit2 name=submit2 disabled=\"disabled\">
    </form>
    ";
    }
    else
    echo "<form name=f1 method=post action=\"xxx.php\">
    <input type=hidden name=uname value=$rec[value]>
    <input type=submit value=\"Accept\" id=submit2 name=submit2 />
    </form>";
    abc
    ;
    echo $str;
    ?>
```

Main theme of my question satisfying the following criteria

```
    First I selected column value
    then I fetch the row for values
    I define one variable to check the values with database values
    then I use if condition to check
    if condition is satisfied disable the form button else enable the form button
    I use heredoc to store and display these values
    If once this process is completed it stores to one variable
    Stored variable value is inserted in to mysql database
    and based on the condition automatically user is able to see the form enable/disable    buttons
```

Example:In users panel I want to display  some links and for each link I display one button like accept according to the condition When user click on that button page is executed and display the button as disable

Give me different suggestions

I don't know this is the only way for this solution

If any other solutions are there please suggest me

Need help

Great Thanks.

Comment: Could you please re-edit your question? Indenting your text marks it up as code, and it makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is outright wrong:

```
<?php
$str=<<<abc    <---starting a heredoc here
$sql=mysql_query("select * from links where column='value'");
```

Once you're in a HEREDOC, you're defining STRINGS. PHP will interpolate variables, but will otherwise **NOT** execute any "code" within that text... What you're doing to do is the equivalent of

```
echo "<?php echo 'foo' ?>"
```

This line will NOT output 'foo'. It'll put the entire `<?php echo 'foo' ?>` as-is, because PHP code cannot be nested within itself like that.

Comment: any possible solutions other than the above script

Comment: Learn basic programming, I guess... there is absolutely NO reason to start your heredoc where it is.